# How to get access_token using vue-google-api package for futher use in Google api?

Tags: vue.js, google-drive-api, access-token, google-oauth, google-picker

i'm new in VueJS and Google API, so i'm doing a implementation of Google Drive into my project, using this vue-google-api
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-api
*I just can use the example code from Google picker, but **i prefer using vue-google-api** for shorter code and further use for other APIs*
so after i signed in (**i successfully signed in** ), i want to make a button that open the picker's modal which allow me to pick up the files in Google Drive (screenshots are below), i use this from the Documentation, this is in my component methods for `@click`:

```
        loadPicker(){
            this.$gapi._libraryLoad('picker')
            .then(picker => {
                console.log('picker object :', picker.api); // Just log it out to see what's this, nothing weird

                var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS); // From Docs
                view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

                var newPicker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder() // From Docs
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .setAppId("MY_PROJECT_ID")
                    .setOAuthToken(THIS_IS_WHAT_IM_MISSING_AKA_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                    .addView(view)
                    .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                    .setDeveloperKey("MY_API_KEY")
                    .setCallback(this.pickerCallback)
                    .build();

                    newPicker.setVisible(true);
                    console.log('send help pls reponse!');

            });            
        },
        pickerCallback(data) {
            var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
            alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
        }
```

and i include the package like this:

```
import VueGoogleApi from 'vue-google-api';

const config = {
  apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
  clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis']
};

Vue.use(VueGoogleApi, config);
```

My screen capture for more details
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkLXh.png
of course it happens, i didn't put my access_token in, i have it responsed right here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD0f6.png, but i don't know how to get it using the **vue-google-api**, **this is Laravel - Vue by the way, if it matters somehow**.
My sign in code if it helps:

```
var mixin = {
    methods:{
        //
        googleSignIn: () => {
            app.$gapi.signIn()
            .then(user => {
                alert('Signed in as ' + user.name);
                console.log('Signed in as '+ user.name);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Not signed in: %s', err.error);
            })
        },
        googleSignOut: () => {
            // Google API 
            app.$gapi.signOut()
            .then(() => {
                alert('Signed out!');
                console.log('Signed out');
            });
        },
        checkGoogleSignIn: () => {
            app.$gapi.isSignedIn()
            .then(result => {
                app.$gapi.currentUser()
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('Signed in as '+ user.name);
                    } else {
                        console.log('No user is connected.');
                    }
                })
            });
        },
        //
    },
}
```

**Thanks for all of your answers**

Answer (score 0):

I did it, i have to init the client again, then call the picker in it's own `then`:

```
            let GoogleAuth;
            let GoogleUser;
            let oauthToken;
            app.$gapi._libraryLoad('auth2') // Init new user to get access_token
            .then(auth2 => {
                auth2.init(
                    {
                        client_id: GoogleApiConfig.clientId,
                        scope: GoogleApiConfig.scope,
                    }
                ).then(() => {
                    GoogleAuth = auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    GoogleUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
                    oauthToken = GoogleUser.Zi.access_token; // Get access_token
                    // Must load the picker when in the promise so it has the permission
                    app.$gapi._libraryLoad('picker') // Call picker API after authentication
                    .then(picker => {
                        var newPicker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                            .setAppId(GoogleApiConfig.projectId)
                            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true)) // My Drive
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true)) // Upload view
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.RECENTLY_PICKED)) // Recently picked
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(false)) // Shared with me
                            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setStarred(true).setLabel('Starred')) // Starred
                            .setDeveloperKey(GoogleApiConfig.apiKey)
                            .setCallback(data => {
                                // var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
                                // Contained in array when select multiple files
                                app.pickedIDs = data.docs;
                            })
                            .build();
                        newPicker.setVisible(true);
                    });
                }).catch(()=> {
                    // If not signed in
                    this.googleSignIn();
                });
            });
```